# Deploy application to EKS Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

After creating an eks cluster with eksctl or aws CLI with the specified node group. Then when I apply my Deployment yaml file, is my Pods distributed among the node group above automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your pod will get deployed on any node in cluster which has sufficient resource to support it.